# Intellij Idea stuck on reading pom.xml while importing android project

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-compiler-plugin

I have problem with Intellij-Idea. IDE stuck on "Looking for avalible profiles - reading pom.xml" while importing as a maven project, Intelij stuck on reading pom also on orginal project. 
I have tried to build project via console `mvn clean install` and it... works perfectly, building project without errors but in Intellij dependency classes still are not avalible to import and shows up as red in code. I don't if that helps but I'm using mbp with OSx yosemite.

project can be found on github:
[wykop offline on github](https://github.com/marcinmierzejewski1024/wykopoffline)

Restarting Ide/computer does not help

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.mierzejewski.wykopoffline</groupId>
        <artifactId>wykop-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>apk</packaging>
        <properties>
            <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <sdk.path>/Users/dom/Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624/sdk</sdk.path>
    </properties>

    <!--<repositories>-->
        <!--<repository>-->
            <!--<id>jitpack.io</id>-->
            <!--<url>https://jitpack.io</url>-->
        <!--</repository>-->
    <!--</repositories>-->



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mcxiaoke.volley</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mikepenz.materialdrawer</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <type>aar</type>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/materialdrawer-3.0.9.aar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>${sdk.path}</path>

                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to use Gradle instead of Maven. Gradle is recommended build system for Android projects. It is also supported by IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio.

Comment: Thats what I've done. Now it's working but honestly all I know about gradle is where to put compile directives:P

Answer (score 1):

you can try to config this into your host file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

This maybe the maven in IDEA force to read localhost first. Then you stuck in reading pom.xml forever.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you can't go past the import window because clicking the "next" button doesn't produce any result?

if that is the issue, then it is a memory problem:

> The default value assigned to Intellij importer is not enough to
>   handle the operation!

I have documented the solution to this issue in a similar question:
[Memory problem as the answer to "Can't import the maven project in IntelliJ Idea"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51875187/1545425)

P.s.: Do not ask me why as i was surprised as well that the selling company could really make such a mistake.